# api one jason python

Tags: python, json

Suppose you are writing a python web client to access an API of an online supermarket. Given below are the API details.

Base URL= http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080

The following product has been entered into the API server by you in the previous question.
However, it has been noted that the entered product's brand should be changed to "Araliya" instead of "CIC".
Write a python program to update the entry on the API server as required. Print the JSON response of the request.

```
{
        "productName":"Araliya Basmathi Rice",
        "description":"White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.",
        "category":"Rice",
        "brand":"CIC",
        "expiredDate":"2023.05.04",
        "manufacturedDate":"2022.02.20",
        "batchNumber":324567,
        "unitPrice":1020,
        "quantity":200,
        "createdDate":"2022.02.24"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBze3.png)

give me the answer
i cant unders tand how to svolwe this one

Comment: You have mistaken Stackoverflow for a free code writing service

Comment: [Stack Overflow homework FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)